# Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop fails at boot with wifi card

Tags: boot, networking, wireless, rfkill

I have an issue with starting Ubuntu up. it will crash when booting up and the last line will say:

```
[  OK  ] Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
```

In which right after the screen will go black. After multiple attempts, I had to go through the Grub Menu to start up my system in Safe Mode. When trying out the desktop in safe mode, the wifi was working on my desktop and I was able to access the internet.

When digging through some research, it seems as though rfkill can be related to a wifi problem. When I removed the wifi card from the desktop, it worked perfectly fine and it was able to boot up with no problems.

I installed the wifi card about 5-6 weeks ago and hadn't had this problem before during boot until last night. What should I check for when searching for the cause of this problem and to fix this so I do not run into this error during boot?